# how to send json from iOS device to rails server

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, json, restkit

I always used parse.com for this sorts of things and get rid of the backend pain but as a developer i wanted to upgrade myself and dived into the rails pool.

right now, i successfully created everything with these methods

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonMutableDictionary
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];
NSLog(@" json data form %@",jsonData);

NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Json string form");
```

and this is the json that i want to send

```
  {
  "id" : 27,
  "login_screen" : 1,
  "last_name_button_clicked" : 0,
  "last_name" : "herose",
  "set_first_name_button_clicked" : 0,
  "first_name" : "george"
}
```

now i'v been looking through all over the places but couldn't find a right way to do this in asynchronous way to not harm the user experience.

and i got absolutely no idea on how to get these key-value pairs in my rails server,

do i create a route in my routes file with GET method?

how will it work?

Any kind of information is useful :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you'd use [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html) to send JSON to a server.

Here's a good NSURLSession [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial).

Hope it helps!